# React.js - componentWillReceiveProps only updates every other this.props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app with React v0.14.6 . The desired functionality is to click on the GoalItem to show the ModalItem. The goal-item has an 'a' tag with attribute onClick that sets {this.state.showModal: true}. The ModalItem is passed  GoalItem's this.state.showModal via a showModal attribute.

To change the state of the ModalItem component such that  this.state.showModal: this.props.showModal, I use setState() in componentWillReceiveProps.

The strange behavior is that the 'a' tag in GoalItem needs to be clicked twice to make the modal appear.The goal is for just one click to suffice.

Thank you in advance for your help. Below is the relevant code.

```
//goal-item.jsx

var React = require('react');
var ModalItem = require('./modal-item');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            name: this.props.goal.name,
            nameChanged: false,
            showModal: false
        }
    },
    open() {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    },
    render() {
        return <a  className="list-group-item"
                   key={this.props.goal.id}
                   onClick={this.open}>
            <ModalItem goal={this.props.goal} showModal={this.state.showModal} />
        </a>
    }
});   

//modal-item.jsx

var React = require('react');
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap/lib/modal'); 
var Button = require('react-bootstrap/lib/button');
module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {showModal: false };
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        this.setState({ showModal: this.props.showModal });
    },
    close() {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>{this.props.goal.name}</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>{this.props.goal.description}</p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `componentWillReceiveProps` you will get new props as argument.
So it should be:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState({ showModal: newProps.showModal });
}
```

Basically this is a place where you can compare new props from argument with old prop by accessing them using `this.props`, and then perform needed updates of state.

See documentation: [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops)